# How to add a Windows 10 Tile-Wide to WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-10

How to add a Windows 10 Tile-Wide or Tile-Large to a Normal Windows WPF Application.

I write a normal windows WPF Application and it's not a universal app. The icon of this application can't change to Wide or Large in Windows 10 Start Menu like native windows 10 application icons.

[image]

Comment: have you tried the linked tool?

Comment: This is totally not related to my question :-(

Comment: @magicandre1981 I need a C# code, XAML or API for my wpf applications and you promote a site and a software!!

Comment: desktop applications (WPF) are not allowed to create tiles: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242183 only universal store apps

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't provide a native way to do it. But there is a 3rd party application called [TileCreator](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10/development/app-tilecreator-create-tiles-to-t3171167) which [allows creating wide and large Tiles for Desktop Application](http://www.intowindows.com/tilecreator-oblytile-for-windows-10/) if you provide pictures as shown in this picture:

[image]